# Resource window doesn't work properly on other systems (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I have created a simple Win32 Project application (not MFC!) in Visual Studio 2012 (Win7 x64).
For the main window I used a modeless window from resources.

Compiled program worked well. Then I tried to run this program on another computer. To do it first of all I compiled it in **Release**, the Runtime Library option was set to **Multi-threaded (/ MT)**.

And I noticed the following problem - on the virtual win7 x64, the program started, but I couldn't move the program's main window with the mouse and there was no reaction to the pressing of the close button. I.e. I can't close the window using system menu.

I also compiled version for WinXP x86. It was the same result. I also noticed another thing - if I place a couple of buttons to window in the designer, and start program on WinXP, then I see the buttons moved down a bit ...

But on the PC where the program was compiled - everything works fine - the window moves with mouse, the system menu works also.

Where can there be a mistake?

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project1.h"


INT_PTR WINAPI Dlg_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
//=========================================================================
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
HWND mainWnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(mainWindow), NULL, (DLGPROC)Dlg_Proc); 
ShowWindow(mainWnd, SW_SHOW);


MSG msg;
BOOL bRet;

    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) 
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
        }
        else if (!IsWindow(mainWnd) || !IsDialogMessage(mainWnd, &msg)) 
        { 
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        } 
    }

return 0;
}
//=========================================================================
INT_PTR WINAPI Dlg_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return TRUE;
        }

        default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

return 0;
}
```

.rc file:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#include "targetver.h"
#endif
#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS
#include "windows.h"
#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Russian (Russia) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_RUS)
LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

mainWindow DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 178
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    mainWindow, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 302
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 171
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // Russian (Russia) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_WIN32PROJECT1       ICON                    "Win32Project1.ico"
IDI_SMALL               ICON                    "small.ico"

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED\r\n"
    "#include ""targetver.h""\r\n"
    "#endif\r\n"
    "#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "#include ""windows.h""\r\n"
    "#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Remarks from `DialogProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469(v=vs.85).aspx):

> You should use the dialog box procedure only if you use the dialog box class for the dialog box. This is the default class and is used when no explicit class is specified in the dialog box template. Although the dialog box procedure is similar to a window procedure, it must not call the `DefWindowProc` function to process unwanted messages. Unwanted messages are processed internally by the dialog box window procedure.

You are doing exactly this - calling `DefWindowProc` from `DialogProc` callback instead of returning `FALSE` to indicate that message has not been processed. Also there should be no need to cast `(DLGPROC)Dlg_Proc`.